# referencing in latex

Tags: reference, latex

I use natbib for referencing in latex file. Using the style plainnat it give me this:

In [29] they present an ...

Is there a way to make it looks like:

Wolska et al. [29] present ...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't too hard to do with natbib. the command you want is `\citeauthor{}` which, for example, gives "Gossens, et al" in the text.

The LaTeX WikiBook ([Natbib section here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Natbib)) is a great resource. Hope this helps!